# Batch File Crashes for No Apparent Reasion

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making a simple batch file that backs up my folders to an external hard drive, and I'm running into some trouble. I've done these types of scripts before, but apparently it was a long time ago because I have no idea why the following script keeps crashing. I imagine that it has something to do with the IF statement, but I can't see anything wrong. If you could help me out, that would be great. Please excuse all the extra echos and stuff, I just like my scripts to look nice.

```
@echo off
title System Backup
cls
echo.
echo System Backup
echo.
set c=
set /P c=Are you sure you want to back up? [Y/N] 
echo %c%
pause
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" (
    echo.
    echo Copying Documents...
    ROBOCOPY "D:\Ryan\Documents" "F:\Ryan\Documents" /mir
    echo.
    echo Copying complete.
    echo.
    pause
    exit
} else (
    echo.
    echo Cancelling backup...
    echo.
    pause
    exit
}
```

Comment: If you remove the first line, you should see where it crashes. If you run the script from the command line instead of double clicking it, you will be able to read any error messages. Please do both of these things and let us know what you see so that we can give you better assistance.

Comment: I forgot to say that I've tried both of the suggestions you mentioned, with neither yielding results. When I run in the CMD with `@echo off`, it just returns to the C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop prompt.

Comment: @Rrrrry123 see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
@echo off
title System Backup
cls
echo.
echo System Backup
echo.
set /P c=Are you sure you want to back up? [Y/N] 
echo %c%
if /I "%c%"=="Y" (
    echo.
    echo Copying Documents...
    ROBOCOPY "D:\Ryan\Documents" "F:\Ryan\Documents" /mir
    echo.
    echo Copying complete.
    echo.
    pause
    exit
) else (
    echo.
    echo Cancelling backup...
    echo.
    pause
    exit
)
```

I simply changed the 2 closing `}` with `)`

Comment: What did you change? Yours looks the same as mine, haha.

Comment: @Rrrrry123 My pleasure. It is always the small syntax issues you miss. if your statements looks fine, your variables check out, look at things like brackets, parenthesis  and their positions etc. :)